# How to change width of image css on the basis of portrait and landscape image

Tags: html, css

Implemented a logo in the box, where width should be 100% if the image is in portrait or square orientation and width should be auto if the image is in landscape orientation.

Comment: Share your code what you have done so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries for this

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  img {
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Hope this may help you.

**DEMO**

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  img {
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg">
```

Comment: I think this is the media query for screen orientation and the OP is asking for the individual image orientation.